# Detecting animation complete from parent iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have the following code:

**MAIN HTML DOCUMENT**

```
  $(function(){              
    $("#i").load(function(){
      var $iframeContents = $(this).contents(),
          $a = $iframeContents.find('#click-me'),         
          $box = $iframeContents.find('#box');         

      $a.click(function(){
        $("#i").animate({height: $box.height(), width: $box.width()})
      });                 
    });       
  });          
<iframe id="i" src='in-frame.html'></iframe>
```

**IFRAME DOCUMENT**

```
  <h1><a id="click-me" href="#">Click Me</a></h1>
  <div id="box">   
  </div>                                                                                                                  
  <script>
  $(function(){                         
    $("#click-me").click(function(){
       $("#box").animate({height: "400px", width: "400px"});
    });
  })
  </script>
```

In the in-frame.html document there is js that animates the `#box` div.  I would like to wait until the animation is complete before calling `$("#i").animate({height: $box.height(), width: $box.width()})`

I feel like I should be listening for the event somehow but I am not exactly sure how to do this.

Note: These are both on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

> .animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] *[, complete]* )
>
> properties: A map of CSS properties that the animation will move
>   toward.
>
> duration: A string or number determining how long the animation will
>   run.
>
> easing: A string indicating which easing function to use for the
>   transition.
>
> *complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.*

Source: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Use a callback function.

Comment: key here is: from the iframe (parent)

Comment: Calling a function that is within the parent document is not going to work here. I need to be able to detect when the animation completes from the main document. Not sure what your answer is mentioning but it does not seem correct.

Comment: In your iFrame you set a callback function on completing the animation.  The callback function calls a function in your main document.  This function "detects" the animation complete and handles whatever situation your page is in or needs to be in.  Maybe it sets a variable that is being checked by a setTimeOut and then clears the timeout, or maybe it starts a timeout and then clears it upon completion.  With such a vague scenario you really aren't giving me much - the answer provided will work provided you properly implement it.

Comment: function IMDONE(){$("#i").animate({height: $box.height(), width: $box.width()});}

Comment: I am giving you plenty to work with, the question is straight forward.  I need to do this all from the parent "MAIN HTML DOCUMENT".  SetTimeout will not work as I will not know when the animation has finished everytime.  I need a more versatile / dynamic solution.  Hence mentioning detection of the animation completion of the #box in the child "IFRAME DOCUMENT".